# Issues with setInterval in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

I am having some confusing behavior using setInterval within useEffect.

I've extracted the logic to an outside function to make sure it works as intended, and it functions exactly as desired; the value of current alternates between the two images every 3 seconds.

```
const rotateImages = (img) => {
  let images = ['investmentGif', 'flashcardsGif'];
  let i = 0;
  let current = images[0];

  setInterval(() => {
    current = images[i];

    if (i === images.length - 1) {
      i = -1;
    }
    i++;
    console.log(current);
    return current;
  }, 3000);

}
```

However when I attempt to do this in useEffect i get some confusing behavior. As far as i can tell logging it out: the interval runs every three seconds, the value of image changes properly every three seconds but the actual rendered image on the screen alternates between displaying flashcardsGif for three seconds then investmentGif for six seconds.

```
  const [image, setImage] = useState(flashcardsGif);

  useEffect(() => {
    let images = [investmentGif, flashcardsGif];
    let i = 0;
    let current = images[0];

    let switcher = setInterval(() => {
      current = images[i];

      if (i === images.length - 1) {
        i = -1;
      }
      i++;
      setImage(current);
      console.log(i, image);
    }, 3000);

    return () => { clearInterval(switcher) }

  });
```

Altering the code to swap between the two images like below works, but the intention is to use a larger number of images

```
  const [image, setImage] = useState(flashcardsGif);

  useEffect(() => {

    let switcher = setInterval(() => {
      image === flashcardsGif ? setImage(investmentGif) : setImage(flashcardsGif);
    }, 3000);

    return () => { clearInterval(switcher) }

  });
```

Comment: useEffect requires a second parameter - a list of its dependencies. Otherwise it runs on every render and is no different from putting that code in the function body of your component.

Comment: @windowsill It's not "no different", it allows for a cleanup function that runs when the component is going to rerender or unmount

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `let i = 0` will be run on every render.

You can simplify by creating a hook that loops through the index of any list.

```
const useStepThrough = ({list, interval}) => {
  const [i, setI] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const switcher = setInterval(() => {
      setI(ii => (ii + 1) % list.length);
    }, interval);

    return () => { clearInterval(switcher) }
  }, [interval, list.length]); // If the caller is careful about creating
  // new references to the list, then it would be better to put `list` in
  // here so it reacts to updated lists.

  return list[i];
};
```